# Finding the (x,y)th number in a number triangle

Tags: haskell, recursion, nodes

I've been given an assignment to find the (x,y)th number in a number triangle. The triangle is defined as follows.

If |x|>y then 0

If (x,y) = (0,0) then 1

Other values are the sum of all incoming paths up to but not including the required node. Going down the triangle the only directions you can go are straight down, diagonally down&left and diagonally down&right.

For example the node (0,2) = 6. This is because there are 3 paths to 6 and each path adds up to 2.

It may be easier to understand using the table below:

[image: Number Triangle]

I'm currently working on making a data type for this triangle.

I was then considering creating an infinite number triangle then making use of Haskell's lazy evaluation to find the value of a given node. Similar to how you might find the nth term in the Fibonacci series outlined on various sites:

```
fibs = 1 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)
```

I'm having real difficulty figuring out how to do this.

Any nudges in the right direction would be very helpful.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Haskell, but I can describe how the recursive algorithm would work and/or implement it in another language. Would that be helpful, or are you strictly concerned with how to express this in Haskell?

Comment: This looked like a cool problem and just as I completed it, the questions gets closed. I guess I will answer its duplicate instead.